# Owner of the fetching not present

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am trying to learn hibernate here and came across this Class:

HelloWorldClient.java

```
public class HelloWorldClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {

EntityManagerFactory emf = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hello-world");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction txn = em.getTransaction();
try {
txn.begin();
Query query = em.createQuery("select student from Guide guide join fetch 
guide.students student");
List<Student> students = query.getResultList(); 
System.out.println(students);
    txn.commit();           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (txn != null) {
            txn.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }

}
}
```

While executing the query I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query 
specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not 
present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch 
join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=student,role=entity.Guide.students,tableName=Student,tabl
eAlias=students1_,origin=Guide guide0_,columns={guide0_.id ,className=entity.Student}}] [select student from entity.Guide guide join fetch 
 guide.students student]at Impl.java:294)
at client.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:31)
```

The Student and the guide have a many to one relationship..

Note:  I am aware that replacing student in the select query with guide will solve the issue, but I am trying to find why it isn't working the other way round.

Comment: `JOIN FETCH` is basically a request to load some other field of the candidate, where you are returning the candidate objects, hence it is pointless. In your case you aren't returning the candidate objects. Arguably though the JPA provider should not throw an exception, and just ignore it, since the JOIN FETCH makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join fetch doesn't make sense here, because it's a performance hint that forces eager loading of the relation.

Here you are practically telling hibernate:

Take all the student from the `Guide join Student` table, and make sure to eager fetch the reference to `Student` in `Guide` entity. But you have no `Guide` entity

If you want the student just select the student from their table and if you need the relation to `Guide` fetched declare it.

```
select student from Student student join fetch 
student.guide guide
```

Or remove the fetch altogether in this case